# Teaching source for putting players on hands?

Tags: books, hand

Is there a teaching source (book/website) that specializes in putting players on hands?

It seems that every other specialty has been addressed (Caro's tells, Sklansky's starting hands, etc.), but I've never seen one exclusively dedicated to putting players on hands as accurately and precisely as possible.

Does such a source exist?  If so, what is it?

Comment: +1 - liked your question!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic book is "how to read a hand" of Ed Miller. You can find the first [here](http://bookos.org/md5/be3514f0c35145a1836402564f44e0d7)
One most advanced and most general is "Let there be range" of South and Nguyen. You can find the last [here](http://bookos.org/md5/5C609500A9A2EFC066596AA9D670AB90)

Update: In "[Harrington on online cash games : 6-max no-limit hold'em](http://www.libgen.info/view.php?id=904978)" there is a great chapter on hand reading.

Comment: finally got around to reading the first one.  wow!  finally, a systematic approach to hand reading.  i wish i could give you more uv.

Comment: +1 I can't recommend the Ed Miller book enough...

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic covered with plenty of examples at most decent poker training sites, such as Card Runners, Deuces Cracked, or Grinderschool. Most of those will require a paid subscription.

Full disclosure: I own Grinderschool. You can find a list of our videos pertaining to hand reading through our keyword search: [70+ videos on reads](http://www.grinderschool.com/video_list.php?subscription_level=Full&keywords=Reads&sort=date%20desc), [40+ videos on hand ranges](http://www.grinderschool.com/video_list.php?subscription_level=Full&keywords=Hand+ranges&sort=date%20desc)